# How to block any alert box using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I dont know from where alert box is displaying on page load.I just want to block this alert box.How to achieve this?

Comment: How can you load js if you don't know from where to load? You can't block an alert directly.

Comment: issue solved by these lines..

<script>
window.realAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function() {};
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how browser compatible this is, so you'll have to experiment with it on your own.  I've tested it in the latest release of Chrome.

```
capture = window.alert;
window.alert = function(){};
// Script loaded here
window.alert = capture;
```

Comment: Or `window.alert = function(msg){console.log(msg)};` but yeah, it's a hack and might not work in the future/all browsers.